# how to calculate the price after each action of adding new product to the cart?

Tags: jquery, action, addition, onchange, cart

let's say that I have a cart.

I have price, and quantity, a give a span with class "price" for prices, and a span for quantity with class "qty".

so it will look like this:

```
<div id="itemsWrapper">
     <div><span class="price">25</span><span class="qty">2</span></div>
     <div><span class="price">40</span><span class="qty">1</span></div>
     ......
</div>
```

I want to calculate the final price, after each time the user add a product to the cart.

here's what I have tried for price, and not working:

```
$("#itemsWrapper").on("change", "#tableItems", function(){
  var price= new Array();
  $(".price").each(function(index) {
      price.push ($(this).text());
  });
  console.log(price);
});
```

Comment: what have you tried? How do items get added to cart? Have access to price and quantity when they are added in order to generate html for cart display

Comment: I've just added what I tried before, the items goes to cart using add to cart button through ajax, I made the classes in order to have access to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got what I want.

I inserted this directly after updating the HTML the cart:

```
var rtp = new Array();
var qty = new Array();

$(".rtp").each(function() {
   rtp.push ($(this).text());
});

$(".qty").each(function() {
   qty.push ($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you need, but I've tried some code for you

```
var total_price = 0;
$("#itemsWrapper div").each( function() {
    price = $(this).find(".price").html();
    quantity = $(this).find(".qty").html()
    total_price += price * quantity;
});
alert(total_price);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cTtyL/

I can probably help you more with regard to hooking up "item added" events, but I need more info from you on how you are trying to bind events.

Comment: this worked alone, but I want to do that each time I add a product to the cart !

Comment: SPrince, how is the item being added? Would you mind pasting codes for that here?

Comment: GiantEnemyCrab, I'm it's afraid a lot of code, but in simple picture, I send an Ajax request depending on product id, then it returns with item id, size, price and I get the quantity from the user then update cart div with those data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to go on a shopping spree on your site with FireBug enabled ;)

You shouldn't be calculating the price on the front-end, using Javascript. Send an AJAX request everytime an item is added to refresh the cart instead.